# Search Code Error

Tags: vba, ms-access

I redid the search code and wrote it as a vba code instead of a query, but now I am running into errors now that it is all setup. The code is below:

The code I am getting is OBJECT REQUIRED 424 and it is highlighting the

```
If Me!txtEmpID Is Not Null Then


Private Sub cmdSearch2_Click()

Dim strSQL As String

strSQL = ""

If Me!txtEmpID Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[EmployeeID] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!txtEmpName Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[EmployeeName] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!cboEEOC Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[EEOC] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!cboGender Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[Gender] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!txtDivision Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[Division] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!cboRR Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[Region] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!cboDD Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[District] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!cboJobGroupCode Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[JobGroupCOde] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!txtCenter Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[Center] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!txtJobD Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[JobDesc] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!cboJobGroup Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[JobGroup] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!cboFunction Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[Function1] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!cboMtgReadyLvl Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[MeetingReadinessRating] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!cboMgrReadyLvl Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[ManagerReadinessRating] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!txtFeedback Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[EmployeeFeedback] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If
If Me!cboDevelopment1 Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"([DevelopmentForEmployee1] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment1 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee2] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment1 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee3] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment1 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee4] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment1 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee5] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment1 & " * ') "
End If

If Me!cboDevelopment2 Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"([DevelopmentForEmployee1] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment2 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee2] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment2 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee3] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment2 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee4] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment2 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee5] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment2 & " * ') "
End If

If Me!cboDevelopment3 Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"([DevelopmentForEmployee1] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment3 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee2] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment3 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee3] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment3 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee4] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment3 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee5] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment3 & " * ') "
End If

If Me!cboDevelopment4 Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"([DevelopmentForEmployee1] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment4 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee2] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment4 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee3] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment4 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee4] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment4 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee5] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment4 & " * ') "
End If

If Me!cboDevelopment5 Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"([DevelopmentForEmployee1] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment5 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee2] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment5 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee3] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment5 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee4] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment5 & " * ' " & _
"OR [DevelopmentForEmployee5] LIKE '*" & Me!Me!cboDevelopment5 & " * ') "
End If

If Me!txtJustification Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[Justification] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!txtNotes Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[Notes] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

If Me!cboChanged Is Not Null Then
strSQL = strSQL & IIf(strSQL = "", "", " AND ") & _
"[Changed] LIKE '*" & Me!txtEmpID & " * ' "
End If

strSQL = "SELECT * FROM [CDData] WHERE " & strSQL

DoCmd.RunSQL strSQL

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking for null in If statements is a little different:

```
 If Not IsNull(Me!txtEmpID) Then
```

And so on.

Comment: That worked, now I am getting an error reading: RUNTIME ERROR 3129 INVALID SQL STATEMEMENT and it has DOCMD.RUNSQL strSQL highlighted

Comment: @user2119980 when it gives you that error look at the value `strSQL` ane make sure that a proper where clause has been created. you could even copy/paste the value (by printing to the immediate window, `?strSQL`) and run the query in the query designer.